# How to get calendar API class definitions and libraries, continued

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, libraries

First off, I find it rather irritation that my original question, [How to get calendar API class definitions and libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171648/how-to-get-calendar-api-class-definitions-and-libraries) was closed. Sorry but it was NOT unfocused. It specifically asked for what libraries I needed to compile the CalendarQuickstart.java sample standalone, without gradle. I think anyone who actually uses this API needs this information and it is not to be found. I did find out the information and will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally got it going through much trial and error. To compile the CalendarQuickstart.java program standalone (w/o gradle) I needed the following jarfiles from google-api-client-assembly-1.30.2-1.30.2.zip which I downloaded from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download (there are 54 jarfiles in that zip!):

google-oauth-client-java6-1.25.0.jar
google-api-client-1.25.0.jar
jetty-6.1.26.jar
google-http-client-1.25.0.jar
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.25.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.25.0.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar
google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev411-1.25.0.jar

In addition I needed guava-core-19.0.0.jar which I downloaded from https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php.

I also had to include my tomcat servlet-api.jar, needed only when authorizing and launching a web page.

Like I said, it would be nice this were documented somewhere. While the gradle tool is useful for proof of concept, it's rather worthless when trying to build a web app jsp program. Hopefully, this will help someone else.